# Extract value with a specific pattern

Tags: c#, regex, string

I found this some time ago but I can't find it now.

I want to parse GPS coordinates having the format `"44°59'59.93\" N "` in C# to get an array of every value. 
Ex:

```
    degree:44
    minutes:59
    seconds:59.93
    direction:"N"
```

I think the solution must be like a regex or a pattern like "{0}°{1}'{2}\"{3}", but I have no clue what function to use for splitting this GPS coordinate into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use capture groups to get the parts you're asking about.

```
string value = @"44°59'59.93"" N";
var match = Regex.Match(value, @"(\d+)°(\d+)'([\d\.]+"")\s*([NSEW])");
if (m.Success) {
    //note that these are all strings and will need to be parsed into ints/doubles
    var degrees = m.Groups[0];
    var minutes = m.Groups[1];
    var seconds = m.Groups[2];
    var direction = m.Groups[3];
}
```

Breaking this down:

- `(`..`)` signify a "group"--part of the match that can be referred to as a contiguous chunk or substring.  (like the opposite of `{0}` placeholders)
- `\d` will match a digit.
- `+` means "one or more", thus `\d+` means "one or more digits"
- `[`..`]` signify a choice of any of the things in the brackets (for the simple case)
- `\s` means "whitespace"
- `*` means "zero or more".  Thus, `\s*` means "there might be some spaces in here, go ahead and take them"

You may want to add some extra `\s*`s in there to catch spaces if there are any.

Answer (score 3):

Split your input according to the below regex.

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, @"[°'""] *");
```

Then get the degree from index 0, minutes from index 1, seconds from index 2, Direction from index 3.

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/57Idtp)

Comment: But this doesn't validate the order of the delimiters.  And if you are just going to split you might as well use `string.Split`.

Comment: i think it would be in the same format. `I wanna parsed GPS coordinate who have always format `

Comment: I find it usefull when I need to parse only the french format but I need to check the english format too so by getting a array of value without knowing if the format is valid, I chose to use the Regex.Match so I can validate that no body can try to enter invalide data or invalide format. Thanks for your help.